# Loop won't work within method, guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, class, methods

I am trying to put together a guessing game, and I think I have everything pretty much laid out. However, for some reason, the for loop within my second method appears to be skipped over. This loop is supposed to be taking guesses from the user and compare them to the generated number in the `number_gen` method.

I'm not even sure if I should be using the `__init__` method, but that is how I started my last assignment on classes so I figured it would be a good place to start.

```
import random

guess = 0
num = 0
attempts = 0

class guessgame:
  def __init__(self, guess, num):
    self.guess = guess
    self.num = num
  
  def number_gen():
    num = random.randrange(1, 100, 1)
    print(num)

  def take_guess():
    
    global attempts
    print("haha")
    for i in range(attempts):
      
      if self.guess != self.num and self.guess == 0:
        input("Enter a number to guess between 1 and 100! ")
    
      elif self.guess != self.num and self.guess >= 1:
        input("Sorry, try again! ")

      elif self.guess == self.num:
        print("You got it!\nIt only took " + attempts + " attempts!")

    attempts = attempts + 1


guessgame.number_gen()
guessgame.take_guess()
```

I am having it print `num` and `haha` just so that I can see it is getting that far.

Comment: You're missing `self` as a parameter to your methods.

Comment: also isn't attempts = 0 on the first iteration? So it would be `for i in range(0):` lastly you need to create an object of the class. I suggest looking up some tutorials on the internet. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/class

Comment: I don't even understand what you are trying to do here; It looks like you need to add `self` to all methods, and then create an instance of `guessgame` with a `guess` and a `num`. However, in the `take_guess` function you just keep on looping `attempt` times, checking the variable that was initialized at the beginning with the number that was in the beginning. What is the use of this loop if you are checking the same two values each time (and therefore getting the same output `attempt` times)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very simple -- you have conflated two concepts in your program

- Maximum allowed `attempts`
- Number of `attempts` made so far

You start your global variable (which is bad design to start with) at 0.  Then you try to loop with:

```
for i in range(attempts):
```

Since `range(0)` is an empty range, you don't execute the loop at all; game over.

You have to separate the concepts: perhaps make a class variable `guess_limit` that is the upper limit for guesses.  Use *that* for the loop limit.  Leave `attempts` as a local variable, not a global.

```
for i in range(guess_limit):
```

---

As for your other comments, you seem to need to work through more examples and exercise on classes.  I don't see why this game uses a class at all: you never instantiate the class, so all do is to introduce more visual and computational overhead in your game.

First, design and implement the game.  *Then* consider whether there's anything worth making into a class.

Comment: OP also needs `self` as a parameter on all methods!

Comment: I don't understand why I have to use classes either honestly, but the assignment tells me to use classes to create the game. Obviously this is just a few functions and variables, so I am as confused as you are on that.

Otherwise, thanks for the comment- this is fantastic and makes perfect sense. Thank you!